# Not sure if two methods are equivalent

Tags: java, object, methods

Are these two methods equivalent? The first one was provided in an internet course I am taking and the second one I came up with on my own. They both seem to be working and giving me the same result, but I am new to Java and might not know what I am doing. Is mine just as good as the first one? I am not sure why the 'this' would be needed at all in this particular situation, but I am most confused about the following line and why it would be necessary:
`Contact contact = this.myContacts.get(i);`

```
private int findContact(String contactName){
    for(int i = 0; i < this.myContacts.size(); i++){
        Contact contact = this.myContacts.get(i);
        if(contact.getName().equals(contactName)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}



private int findContact(String contactName){
    for(int i = 0; i < myContacts.size(); i++){
        if(myContacts.get(i).getName().equals(contactName)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: They are exactly the same code. The only difference is that in the first you store `myContacts.get(i)` into a variable, while in the second you don't.

Comment: And I'd be surprised if the compiler didn't optimize out that variable and generate the exact same code.

Comment: The immediate variable `contact` is not necessary. However, they author *may* have added it to make it better readable. This is subjective, however.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reference to the current instance which can be used to access its members. If an identifier is unambiguous (like `myContacts` is in this case), it's completely optional.
The two methods have the same functionality. The only difference in the implementation is that the first one extracts `myContacts.get(i)` to a local variable and the second doesn't. This has no bearing on the functionality, though.

Answer (score 0):

If the class that the method is located in contains an instance variable called `myContacts`, then it is good practice to use `this` to specify the fact that you are using the specific instance's `myContacts` ArrayList (or whatever `myContacts` is).

To be honest, since there is not another variable in the method, I wouldn't use `this` in this scenario. But, you definitely can.

I'll give you an example of when using `this` is a good idea.

```
public class Example {
    int index;

    private void changeIndex (int index){
       this.index = index;
    }
}
```

In this scenario, the parameter's name is the same as the instance variable's name. You could specify which variable you are referring to in the code by using `this`.